Memory limitations for web workers
I have spent a couple hours searching an answer for this, a simple I thought, question. Can't seem to find one. Is there any doc on that? Anyone can share anything about memory limitations for the web workers?
Thanks

There’s a deprecated API performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit. Is this in reference to a browser runtime or one with system bindings (e.g. Deno/Node)?

Browser runtime.
